# MVC application gives an error with routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I installed a MVC app on one of the machines and it works great. With the same code base, when I install it on a different machine, I get the following error:

```
A route named "myroute" is already in the route collection. 
Route names must be unique
```

This makes me want to say something is not correctly installed on the the second machine. Any clues on what may be installed incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried grepping the application folder for `myroute` on the machine with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a installation problem, this sounds like a code problem, most likely with Routes in your *Areas* conflicting with other routes.

How/when did you get that error? Which URL? Did you request the same URL on both machines?

Do a search in your code-base for "myroute" to be doubly safe.

Comment: I get the error on the home page. Yes, same URL from both machines. I thought it could be the code problem, but I thought I would have had the problem from the other machine as well if it was a code problem.

Comment: @DotnetDude - first time you have installed on that second machine? How did you install? Web Deploy? Manual publish? What are you running, IIS7? Could be old stuff lying around in bin directory.

Comment: MSDeploy. Running IIS 7. No, verified that old stuff is not lying around in the bin. Dont you think its a non code issue?

Comment: If your saying the URL is the same on both machines, then yes - it sounds like a non-code issue. Is this the first time you've deployed on that machine? Maybe run the asp.net iis reg tool again?

Comment: It was the code related issue like you said. After finding all occurrences of the routing path, we had a duplicate that was causing the issue.

Comment: @DotnetDude - hehe, ah well - glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 5):

Check your bin folder. Maybe there is another .dll that adds the same route to the RouteCollection.

This happened to me when I was renaming a project.
I had 2 .dlls in my bin folder:

1. MyProject.Web.dll
2. MyProjectNewName.Web.dll

Comment: Yep - that's what happened to me, too! I hate to think how long it might have taken to find that on my own! Thanks!